# Overloading templated variadic operator with rvalue reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, operator-overloading, variadic-templates

Here's my definition:

```
template<typename ... TL>
struct TemplatedType { };

template<typename ... TL>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, TemplatedType<TL ...> & sp)
{
    // do stuff

    return is;
}
```

And usage:

```
std::istringstream iss("I'd like some pancakes, please");
TemplatedType<int> a;
iss >> a;
```

And it works just fine, but **I'd like to receive the templated arguments as r-value reference**:

```
template<typename ... TL>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, const TemplatedType<TL && ...> & sp) {...}
```

And then, the compiler starts yelling:

> C2678 binary '>>': **no operator found** which takes a left-hand operand
>   of type 'std::istringstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Where's the problem?

---

Motivation:
I'd like to make a `split` function that can be used in this way:

```
std::istringstream iss("alpha:=10/50.1");

std::string x;
int y;
double z;

iss >> split(x, ':', '=', y, '/', z); // sets x=alpha, y=10, z=50.1
```

So the function needs to be able to receive both l-value and r-value references.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? It's really weird that you want to do that IMO. What you have written basically only accepts template parameters that are references.

Comment: `TemplatedType<int>` != `TemplatedType<int&&>` != `TemplatedType<int>&&`

Comment: @Rakete1111 I've added motivation to the question.

Comment: I feel like there's information missing here. Please show some **complete** working code and point out what's lacking in it.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question.

Jarod42 explained where is the problem: if you define a `TemplatedType<int> a;`, this can match

```
template<typename ... TL>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is,
                         const TemplatedType<TL ...> & sp)
```

but can't match

```
template<typename ... TL>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, 
                         const TemplatedType<TL & ...> & sp)
```

because you have a `int` and is required a `int&`.

But how to get working

```
iss >> split(x, ':', '=', y, '/', z);
```

?

Well... I suppose you can put a `std::tuple` inside `TemplatedType`

```
template <typename ... TL>
struct TemplatedType
 { std::tuple<TL...> t; };
```

so `split()` (I've renamed it `mySplit()`) simply become

```
template <typename ... TL>
TemplatedType<TL...> mySplit (TL && ... al)
 { return { std::forward_as_tuple(al...) }; }
```

and from

```
mySplit(x, ':', '=', y, '/', z);
```

where `x` is a `std::string`, `y` is a `int` and `z` is a `double`, you obtain a `TemplatedType<std::string &, char, char, int &, char, double &>`.

You can write an `operator<<()` that call a first helper function

```
template <typename ... TL>
std::istream & operator>> (std::istream & is,
                           TemplatedType<TL...> const & sp)
 {
   myHelper1(is, sp, std::index_sequence_for<TL...>{});

   return is;
 }
```

and the first helper function extract element in the tuple contained in `sp` and call a second helper function

```
template <typename ... TL, std::size_t ... IL>
void myHelper1 (std::istream & is,
                TemplatedType<TL...> const & sp,
                std::index_sequence<IL...> const &)
 { myHelper2(is, std::get<IL>(sp.t)...); }
```

The second helper function is a little more complicated.

It's a recursive set of function that consumes one/two elements every call.

First of all, the ground (terminal) case

```
void myHelper2 (std::istream &)
 { }
```

Then the special `std::string` case with a following constant `char`, the delimiter (without a delimiter, if you simply write`is >> s`, you get the full string contained in `is`)

```
template <typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream & is, std::string & s, char const & delim,
                TS && ... ts)
 {
   std::getline(is, s, delim);

   myHelper2(is, std::forward<TS>(ts)...);
 }
```

Next the version that receive a constant char (as `:`, `=` and `/`, in your example; but the first one is consumed as delimiter for the string) and discard a `char` from `is` (and, if you want, check if the discarded char is the same argument char)

```
template <typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream & is, char const ch, TS && ... ts)
 {
   char ch2;

   is >> ch2;

   // check if `ch` == `ch2`? exception otherwise?

   myHelper2(is, std::forward<TS>(ts)...);
 }
```

Last the general case, that receive a generic (type `T`) reference

```
template <typename T, typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream & is, T & t, TS && ... ts)
 {
   is >> t;

   myHelper2(is, std::forward<TS>(ts)...);
 }
```

The following is a full example.

Works starting from C++14 because `std::index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence_for` are introduced in C++14. But if you want a C++11 solution, it's simple to write a sobstitute for they

```
#include <tuple>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... TL>
struct TemplatedType
 { std::tuple<TL...> t; };

void myHelper2 (std::istream &)
 { }

template <typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream &, char const, TS && ...);

template <typename T, typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream &, T &, TS && ...);

template <typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream & is, std::string & s, char const & delim,
                TS && ... ts)
 {
   std::getline(is, s, delim);

   myHelper2(is, std::forward<TS>(ts)...);
 }

template <typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream & is, char const ch, TS && ... ts)
 {
   char ch2;

   is >> ch2;

   // check if `ch` == `ch2`? exception otherwise?

   myHelper2(is, std::forward<TS>(ts)...);
 }

template <typename T, typename ... TS>
void myHelper2 (std::istream & is, T & t, TS && ... ts)
 {
   is >> t;

   myHelper2(is, std::forward<TS>(ts)...);
 }

template <typename ... TL, std::size_t ... IL>
void myHelper1 (std::istream & is,
                TemplatedType<TL...> const & sp,
                std::index_sequence<IL...> const &)
 { myHelper2(is, std::get<IL>(sp.t)...); }

template <typename ... TL>
std::istream & operator>> (std::istream & is,
                           TemplatedType<TL...> const & sp)
 {
   myHelper1(is, sp, std::index_sequence_for<TL...>{});

   return is;
 }


template <typename ... TL>
TemplatedType<TL...> mySplit (TL && ... al)
 { return { std::forward_as_tuple(al...) }; }

int main ()
 {
   std::istringstream iss("alpha:=10/50.1");

   std::string x;
   int y{};
   double z{};

   iss >> mySplit(x, ':', '=', y, '/', z);

   std::cout << "- x: " << x << std::endl;  // print alpha
   std::cout << "- y: " << y << std::endl;  // print 10
   std::cout << "- z: " << z << std::endl;  // print 50.1
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically possible if `TemplatedType` is implemented with the same way as `std:tuple` (or this is a tuple) and there are `>>` operators exist for all members types.

For example:

```
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

namespace detail {

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct seq { };

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq : gen_seq<N - 1, N - 1, Is...> { };

template<std::size_t... Is>
struct gen_seq<0, Is...> : seq<Is...> { };

template<typename T, typename F, std::size_t... Is>
void for_each(T&& t, F&& f, seq<Is...>)
{
    auto l = { (f(std::get<Is>(t)), 0)... };
}

template<typename... Ts, typename F>
void tuple_for_each(std::tuple<Ts...>& t, F&& f)
{
    for_each(t, std::forward<F>(f), detail::gen_seq<sizeof...(Ts)>());
}

class deserializer {
    deserializer(const deserializer&) = delete;
    deserializer& operator=(const deserializer&) = delete;
public:
    constexpr deserializer(std::basic_istream<char>& is) noexcept:
        is_(is)
    {}
    template<typename any_type>
    void operator()(any_type& val) {
        is_ >> val;
    }
private:
    std::basic_istream<char>& is_;
};

} // namespace detail

template<typename...__tl>
std::basic_istream<char>& operator >> (std::basic_istream<char>& s, std::tuple<__tl...> &out)
{
    detail::tuple_for_each( out, detail::deserializer(s) );
    return s;
}


int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    std::cout<< "Please input a digit" << std::endl;
    std::tuple<int> int_only_tuple;
    std::cin >> int_only_tuple;
    std::cout<< "A digit: " << std::get<0>(int_only_tuple)  << std::endl;

    std::cout<< "Please input two strings" << std::endl;

    std::tuple<std::string, std::string> in;

    std::cin >> in;

    std::cout << "First string: " << std::get<0>(in) << std::endl;
    std::cout<< "Second string: " << std::get<1>(in) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

See also:

- [Boost
  mp11](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html)
  for generic tuple_for_each
- [Boost xpressive](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/xpressive.html) for compile time regexp you trying to implement
- [Boost spirit](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html) for compile time LL parser framework

Comment: `gen_seq` can be replaced by `std::index_sequence`

Comment: If you have C++14 not for C++11.